# Regex Pattern for string replace

Tags: c#, regex

I have a sentence, "Name # 2" ,

I need to replace '#', with "No.",

Final sentence needs to be "Name No. 2".

Code -

```
string sentence = Regex.Replace("Name # 2", "\\#\\b", "No.");
```

Apparently the Regex.Replace fails to replace '#' with 'No', is there a correct way to approach the problem, via a regular expression.
thanks
The reason I am looking for a regex pattern is because there is a generic code which executes which looks something like below

```
     string pattern = string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", context);

     sentence = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(sentence, pattern, suggestion);
```

context - "#"

sentence - "Name # 2"

suggestion - "No."

Expected sentence - "Name No. 2"

Actual sentence - "Name # 2"

context - "were"

sentence - "He were going"

suggestion - "was"

Expected sentence - "He was going"

Actual sentence - "He was going"

context - "a"

sentence - "He was at a point in time going."

suggestion - "z"

Expected sentence - "He was at z point in time going"

Comment: OMG! Why a Regex?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I have edited my question.

Comment: The `\b` matches a word boundary (between alphanumeric and other). There is no such boundary next to that `#` in your input.

Comment: The edit still does not explain why a Regex is needed. Both cases seem to be solvable by a simple string replace.

Comment: @ThomasWeller  I needed to replace a in a sentence like "He was at a point in time going home", I ended up replacing all the 'a's available in the sentence, hence went for regex!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current regex won't match if the `#` is preceded with a *word* char, a letter, digit or an underscore. That happens because a word boundary meaning is context dependent.

Replace it with any of the fixes below:

```
string pattern = string.Format(@"(?<!\w){0}(?!\w)", Regex.Escape(context));
                                 ^^^^^^    ^^^^^^
```

The `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` are context-independent and will match a word if not preceded/followed with a word char.

Or, use

```
string pattern = string.Format(@"(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)", Regex.Escape(context));
```

to only match a word inside whitespace(s) as `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind requires the whitespace or the start of the string before the "word", and the negative lookahead `(?!\S)` requires the end of string or whitespace after the "word".

Note that `Regex.Escape` is a must when you deal with user-input/dynamic pattern building and need to use a *literal* string inside the regex pattern. It will escape all the special chars (like `?`, `+`, etc.) that could ruin the pattern otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

```
string test = "Name # 2";

test = test.Replace("#", "No.");
```

Comment: Sorry I needed to go via Regular expression,

Comment: test = Regex.Replace(test, "#", "No.");

Comment: @Sandepku you should explain (edit your post) why you *need* to use a regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
string sentence = Regex.Replace("Name # 2", "#", "No.");
```

# does not have to escaped, therefore there is no need for the backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex you can do it like so:

```
Regex.Replace("Name # 2", "#", "No.")
```

Or just a plain old string.Replace:

```
"Name # 2".Replace("#", "No.");
```